# React Native Image Unable to resolve module

Tags: reactjs, native, resolve

Unable to resolve "./assets/images/hamburger@2x.png" from "App.js"
How can fix this?

The code:

[image: screenshot view code]

The error message:

[image: screenshot error message]

Comment: I Fixed. File name is hamburger@2x to hamburger-2x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Fixed. File name is hamburger@2x to hamburger-2x
Worked

Answer (score 0):

just require image **without @2x** like this

```
require("./assets/images/hamburger.png")
```